# Trigonometry equation, odd-function.

Tags: trigonometry

So I have the following equation:

$\sin\left(x-\frac{\pi}{6}\right) + \cos\left(x+\frac{\pi}{4}\right)=0$

It should be solved using the fact that Sin is an odd function, I can not really get the gripp of how and what I need to do? Any sugestions?

Comment: Why not to try  expanding the two terms first ?

Comment: Do you mean by using the trigonometric addition formulas?

Comment: Yes; this is just the first idea which came to my mind.

Comment: I have tried this, but all I end up with is the same expression as i start with, or an expression that I can not solve.

Comment: You can solve it. Just use the hint given by BLAZE and put the numbers; you should end with something looking like $a\sin(x)+b\cos(x)=0$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So i found the solution using the fact that Sin is odd, here is my solution:

$\sin\left (x-\frac{\pi}{6}\right ) + \cos\left (x+\frac{\pi}{4}\right ) = 0\Leftrightarrow \cos\left (x+\frac{\pi}{4}\right ) = -\sin\left (x-\frac{\pi}{6}\right )$

Since **sin is an odd function**, $-\sin\left (x-\frac{\pi}{6}\right ) = \sin\left (x-\frac{\pi}{6} + \pi\right )$

This the gives the following:
$\cos\left (x+\frac{\pi}{4}\right ) = \sin\left (x-\frac{\pi}{6} + \pi\right ))\Leftrightarrow \cos\left (x+\frac{\pi}{4}\right ) = \cos\left (\frac{\pi}{2} -\frac{5\pi}{6} -x\right )$

This happends when:
$x + \frac{\pi}{4} = \frac{-2\pi}{6}-x+n2\pi \Leftrightarrow x=\frac{-7\pi}{24}+n\pi$

Thanks alot for the help, special thanx to @BLAZE, you gave me the hints to find the solution.

Comment: You're welcome.

Answer (score 4):

$$\cos(x+\frac\pi4)=\sin(\frac\pi4-x)$$ and
the equation turns to

$$\sin(x-\frac\pi6)=\sin(x-\frac\pi4),$$

i.e.

$$2x-\frac{5\pi}{12}=(2k+1)\pi.$$

Comment: @ Yves i dint get your step after you got sin on both the sides as when you remove sine eqn is 0=-π/6+π/4??

Comment: @ArchisWelankar: $a=b$ is not the only solution of $\sin(a)=\sin(b)$...

Answer (score 1):

Sorry that this approach does not use the oddness of the Sine function, after I finishing writing this it was too late for me to turn back and utilize that property.

Using trigonometric addition formulae as mentioned in the comments:

$$\sin(A \pm B)= \sin A\cos B\pm\cos A\sin B$$
$$\cos(A \pm B)= \cos A\cos B\mp\sin A\sin B$$
Write $$\sin\left(x-\frac{\pi}{6}\right) + \cos\left(x+\frac{\pi}{4}\right)=0$$

as $$\sin(x)\cos\left(\frac{\pi}{6}\right)-\cos(x)\sin\left(\frac{\pi}{6}\right)+\cos(x)\cos\left(\frac{\pi}{4}\right)-\sin(x)\sin\left(\frac{\pi}{4}\right)$$

$$=\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}\sin(x)-\frac{1}{2}\cos(x)+\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\cos(x)-\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\sin(x)$$

$$=\cos(x)\left(\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}-\frac{1}{2}\right)+\sin(x)\left(\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}-\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\right)$$

$$\implies\cos(x)\left(\frac{2-\sqrt{2}}{2\sqrt{2}}\right)+\sin(x)\left(\frac{\sqrt{6}-2}{2\sqrt{2}}\right)=0$$

Since
$$\cos(x)\ne 0$$

$$\implies\left(\frac{2-\sqrt{2}}{2\sqrt{2}}\right)+\tan(x)\left(\frac{\sqrt{6}-2}{2\sqrt{2}}\right)=0$$

$$\implies\tan(x)\left(\frac{\sqrt{6}-2}{2\sqrt{2}}\right)=\left(\frac{\sqrt{2}-2}{2\sqrt{2}}\right)$$

$$x=\tan^{-1}\left(\frac{\sqrt{2}-2}{\sqrt{6}-2}\right)$$

$$x=\tan^{-1}\left(\frac{(\sqrt{2}-2)(\sqrt{6} + 2)}{(\sqrt{6}-2)(\sqrt{6} + 2)}\right)=\tan^{-1}\left(\frac{(\sqrt{2}-2)(\sqrt{6} + 2)}{2}\right)$$

$$=\tan^{-1}{(\sqrt{2}+\sqrt{3}-\sqrt{6}-2)}+k\pi$$

where $k \in \mathbb{N}$

Comment: The final answer can be simplified.

Comment: Your value is correct, though (modulo $\pi$).

Comment: Hem, the function is periodic.

Comment: Well, the answer is correct, but I do not think that this is the method that should be used. This method does not include using that Sin(x) is an odd function.

Comment: @Yves Oh yes I see what you mean, $\pi$ is periodicity for $\tan x$

Comment: @Per Yes good point, I kind of lost track of that condition, sorry

Answer (score 1):

More unorthodoxly, we first take the midpoint of $x-\frac{\pi}{6}$ and $x + \frac{\pi}{4}$ before applying the angle sum and difference identities:

Let $A = x + \frac{\pi}{24}$ (the midpoint). Then we need

$$\sin\left(A - \frac{5\pi}{24}\right) + \cos \left(A + \frac{5\pi}{24}\right) = 0$$
$$\sin A\cos\frac{5\pi}{24} - \cos A\sin\frac{5\pi}{24} + \cos A\cos\frac{5\pi}{24} - \sin A\sin\frac{5\pi}{24} = 0$$
$$\sin A\left(\cos \frac{5\pi}{24} - \sin \frac{5\pi}{24}\right) + \cos A\left(-\sin\frac{5\pi}{24} + \cos \frac{5\pi}{24}\right) = 0$$

$$\left(-\sin\frac{5\pi}{24} + \cos \frac{5\pi}{24}\right)\left(\sin A + \cos A\right) = 0$$

so we need

$$\sin A + \cos A  = 0$$
$$\tan A = -1$$
$$\tan \left( x + \frac{\pi}{24}\right) = -1$$

which can be solved directly as per normal.